# Perforce checkin error : Execution of /perforce/master/utils/p4trigger/FixCheck.pl aborted due to compilation errors

Tags: perforce

I am trying to submit one changelist and getting following error. Not able to find any possible reasons for this and it looks beyond my changes. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
'FixAddCheck' validation failed: "my" variable $sChange masks earlier declaration in same scope at /perforce/master/utils/p4trigger/FixCheck.pl line 120.
"my" variable $sFixCnt masks earlier declaration in same statement at /perforce/master/utils/p4trigger/FixCheck.pl line 122.
syntax error at /perforce/master/utils/p4trigger/FixCheck.pl line 106, near "){"
syntax error at /perforce/master/utils/p4trigger/FixCheck.pl line 116, near "} elsif"
syntax error at /perforce/master/utils/p4trigger/FixCheck.pl line 125, near "}"
Execution of /perforce/master/utils/p4trigger/FixCheck.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Perforce administrator has set up a Perl script as a pre-submit trigger and the script has a bug in it that is causing the trigger to fail (and reject the submit).  Forward these errors to your admin so they can debug (or disable) the trigger script.